# iOS - How to see the output of printf on the iphone?

Tags: ios, xcode, printf, nslog, syslog

I have a jailbroken iPhone and I am working an application that contains a `.c` file which has several `printf` statements.  The application I am working on incorporates serial connectivity, i.e. pin 12 and 13 of the dock connector.  That being said I can not use the console within Xcode to view the output of the `printf` statement because I have a custom made dock connector (not connected to the computer) hooked up to the phone when the app is running

I can ssh into the phone, and I am able to view the output of an `NSLog` using syslogd with `/var/log/syslog`  The printf statements in the .c file are not outputting to `/var/log/syslog` so is there a way I can view the `stdout` on the iPhone through and SSH session?  Or is there way I can redirect / tell the `.c` file to output to `/var/log/syslog`?

Either solution will work.  Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you are jailbroken, the most straightforward way it to use the [Syslog SBSetting toggle](http://modmyi.com/cydia/sbsettingssyslogd)

Will enable logging to `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: I already have `syslogd` installed on the iPhone, and the output of the `printf` messages is not outputting to the `var/log/syslog`

Comment: Read the linked description : it does not require nor rely on syslogd. Have a try and tell me how it goes

Comment: Do I have to install SBSettings in order to use this logging feature?

Comment: Ehh, I'll probably come up with a different solution, didn't really want to install SBSettings just so I could see some log messages.